# complex nt problem

Tags: number-theory

If a, b, and c are integers that satisfy $abc + a + b + c = ab + bc + ca + 2013$, then find the number of possible values of b.

Comment: What does this have to do with complex numbers?

Comment: I mean complex number theory....

Comment: Sorry, my first post had some issues. I edited it, and I think the solution is complete.

Answer (score 1):

We know (from experience or insight) that 
$$(a-1)(b-1)(c-1) = abc-ab-ac-bc+a+b+c-1$$
Your problem can be reordered to become (you can verify by yourself)
$$(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)=2012$$
Now, we split $2012$ into its prime factors of $2,2,503$. The term $(b-1)$ can be any of those three or combinations of those three, listed here: $\pm1,2,4,503,1006,2012$, so there are **$12$** values of $b$, which are $-2011, -1005, -502, -3, -1, 0, 2, 3,5,504, 1007,2013$.

Answer (score 0):

One has $(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)=abc-ab-bc-ca+a+b+c-1=2012$.

Then one has $b-1$ can be $\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 4,\pm 503$. So $b$ can be $-502,-3,-1,0,2,3,5,504$.